# Can I use RJ45 to connect to the Internet?

Tags: internet, rj-45

Is it okay to use RJ 45 as the Ethernet cable? 
For this [computer](http://www.planar.com/reseller/pdfR/touchscreen/ds-planar-PA1575RXP.pdf) , the LAN interface is RJ45.

Can it be connected to a router? Any speed difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name `RJ45` is a kind of a historical accident. It originally referred to a telephone company wiring standard. Common 10/100/1000 Ethernet wiring uses the same physical jack, but a different wiring. But since the jack was the same, it took the name. So now `RJ45` basically refers to just the jack. Technically, it should have been called [8P8C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8P8C_modular_connector#8P8C), but it is what it is.

So when they say `RJ45`, they just mean the standard Ethernet jack that all common wired devices have. A regular Ethernet cable will connect correctly to that jack.